# Why does $T(\lg u)$ have the same complexity as $T(u)$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I have seen on this video ([van Embde Boas Trees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmReJCupbNU&t=312s)) at time 8:00 that:
$$T(\lg u) = T(\lg u/2) + \mathcal{O}(1) = \mathcal{O}(\lg \lg u)$$
and that
$$T(u) = T(\sqrt{u}) + \mathcal{O}(1) = \mathcal{O}(\lg \lg u)$$
have the same complexity.

I don't see the connection on why these two recurrences have the same complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the first recurrence
$$
T(\lg(u)) = T\left(\frac{\lg (u)}2\right) + \mathcal O(1) = \mathcal O(\lg(\lg(u)))
$$
you have
$$
\frac{\lg(u)}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \lg(u) = \lg\left(u^{\frac 1 2}\right) = \lg(\sqrt{u})
$$
so you can rewrite it as
$$
T(\lg(u)) = T(\lg(\sqrt{u})) + \mathcal O(1) = \mathcal O(\lg(\lg(u))).
$$
Then letting $T'(z) = T(\lg z)$ you obtain
$$
T'(u) = T'(\sqrt{u}) + \mathcal O(1) = \mathcal O(\lg(\lg(u))).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The first one, if you change variables to $x = \lg u$, reads $T(x) = T(x/2) + O(1)$ and assume $x=2^k$, you get
$$
\begin{split}
T(x)
 &= T(x/2) + O(1) \\
 &= \left(T(x/2^2) + O(1)\right) + O(1)\\
 &= T(x/2^2) + 2O(1) \\
 &= T(x/2^3) + 3O(1) \\
 & \ldots \\
 &= T(x/2^k) + O(k) \\
 &= T(1) + O(k) = O(k)
\end{split}
$$
since $x=2^k$ we have $k = \lg x$ and thus $T(x) = O(\lg x)$ or in the original variables, $T(\lg u) = O(\lg \lg u)$.

Can you use a similar argument for the second recurrence?